# How to add only a (sub) capacity to an user role?

Tags: permissions, user-roles

I know I can add capabilities to the any role using the role object and add_cap via functions.php

```
<?php
   // get the the role object
   $editor = get_role('editor');
   // add $cap capability to this role object
   $editor->add_cap('edit_theme_options');
?>
```

The [**list of capabilities**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_theme_options) shows that "edit_theme_options" allows access to almost all items under *Appearance* (all but *edit theme*). **What I wold like to do is add capacity to access only *Appearance>Menu* to a role. Is this possible without modifying the core?**

The two most popular ACL editing plugins ([Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) and [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/)) don't allow for this as they only use the default *list of capabilities*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stupid, but you can't. (Not without editing core, anyway.) Right at the top of the nav-menus.php source code is an `edit_theme_options` check that's not filterable.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-admin/nav-menus.php

If you're not concerned about your editors trying anything too shady, you could simply hide the menu items using a plugin like Adminimize or Admin Menu Editor.

Of course, you could also open a ticket at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ to try to get the core devs to change this.

Comment: Great, thanks! It doesnt bother me to use a plugin... Adminimize together with the "User Role Editor" plugin  did it: the newly created role "SuperEditor" has all the permissions given to Editors plus manage APPEARANCE>MENU (if someone can create a page, they should also be able to manage the menu, right:)